# How do I change the color of a tab when the sum of cells =0

Tags: vba, excel, tabs

Basically, I want the tab for the sheet to turn green when the sum of the column = zero.  I inserted the code below but it is not working.  I think it is tied to the fact that the target cell has a Sum Function in it [Cell G30 has a Sum Function (=SUM(G4:G17)]

Any help you could provide would be more than welcome.  Have a great day.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160930
    If Target.Address = "$G$30" Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case "0"
            Me.Tab.Color = vbGreen
        Case Else
            Me.Tab.Color = vbRed
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: in which topic/programming language is your question? pleas tag it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worksheet_Change() event is triggered based on the `Target` value
(your code works only if cell G30 is changed by hand, not by a formula)

So there are 2 options

- Either check G30, regardless of which cell was updated by hand in Worksheet_Change()
- Or check the calculated value of cell G30 in the Worksheet_Calculate() event

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Me.Tab.Color = vbRed

    If Me.Range("G30").Value2 = 0 Then Me.Tab.Color = vbGreen

End Sub
```

---

Or

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Select Case Me.Range("G30").Value2

        Case 0:     Me.Tab.Color = vbGreen

        Case Else:  Me.Tab.Color = vbRed

    End Select

End Sub
```

---

Make sure to implement one or the other, not both at the same time

Comment: Thank you.  Thank you. Thank you.  I am but a simple social worker and this has been driving me crazy.  May your weekend be long and happy.